# Can I export the list of projects from the Iguazio cluster, how?

Tags: mlops

I would like to export all my projects from an Iguazio cluster, how will I be able to do it?

Answer (score 0):

It's actually pretty straightforward.
Just run the following code snippet in your jupyter notebook:

```
import mlrun
db = mlrun.get_run_db()
list = db.list_projects()
for i in list:
  print(i.to_yaml())
```

You can get the yaml of all the projects. If you need specific information about a project, you can parse the info from the yaml.